# JAVA: Addition from start to end using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I need help with this recursion method. I need it to add the integers from a starting point up to the end point.

```
    public static int sumInts(int begin, int end){
    if (begin == end)
        return begin + end;
    else
        return sumInts(begin+1,end);
}
```

Example output should be:

 `Start: 1
 End: 4
 Sum is: 10`

But I'm getting `8` as my output for those particular input. I know it's the condition that's ruining this but I can't seem to figure it out..

Comment: What do you expect in case `sumInts(1,1)`?

Comment: If you look closely at your code it is essentially `return end+end;`

Comment: In 5th line change your code to - return begin + sumInts(begin+1,end);

Comment: @PM77-1 I should've seen that. Start 1 and end 1 would just be 1.

Comment: @SanjitKumarMishra yeah, that worked with the solution below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But I'm getting 8 as my output for those particular input.

It's normal. It will go to the `else` block everytime but the last time, because both `begin` and `end` will be `4` and it will return `4 + 4 = 8`.

You should do something like this:

```
public static int sumInts(int begin, int end){
    if (begin == end)
        return end; // return the last number
    else
        return begin + sumInts(begin+1,end); // sum the current number with the recursion result
}
```

And this can of course be done the other way - by decreasing `end` instead of increasing `begin`.

```
public static int sumInts(int begin, int end){
    if (begin == end)
        return begin;
    else
        return end + sumInts(begin,end-1);
}
```